# How can I see what exception causes a 500 error in my rest resource in Payara?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, payara

I'm developping a JEE 7 app in Payara.

I have a rest resource that returns a 500 error when I test it.
No exceptions shows up on the logs.

How can I see what exception causes a 500 error in my rest resource in Payara ?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the REST method and stepping through your code line-by-line?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the problem happenned during the JSON serialization and it didn't show during debug. After an investigation I was able to pinpoint the problem, but a stacktrace would have helped greatly.